# Can someone help explain what this C algorithm is doing?

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I have been looking at this C code but am not sure what exactly it is doing. I don't understand the use of multiple if statements of finding statements.

```
int f(char *s) {
  char *p = s;
  int c = 1;
  while (*p == ’ ’)
    ++p;
  while (*p != ’\0’) {
    if ( *p < ’0’ || *p > ’9’ ) {
      printf("Error!\n"); return 0;
    }
  ++p; }
  for (--p; p >= s; --p) {
    if (*p == ’ ’) *p = ’0’;
    *p += c;
    if (*p > ’9’) {
      *p = ’0’; c = 1;
    } else
      c = 0;
    if (c == 0) break;
  }
  if (c != 0) {
    printf("Error!\n");
    return 0;
}
return 1; }
```

Comment: That is not valid C code. https://wandbox.org/permlink/2flW7TlwG4y6Oynz

Comment: What is the general idea? Did this code fall upon you from the heavens? Didn't the place you got it from give some explanation?

Comment: How about *you* describe what the code does to us.  If you get it wrong, people may give pointers.   You'll learn more of use that way, than if people just told you what's going on with no effort on your part.    And, BTW, what the code does it pretty simple.

Comment: Replace all `’` with `'`.

Comment: If a string contains an integer (with leading spaces) increment this integer by one.  Return 1 on success and 0 on failure.

Comment: just a tip: use brackets everytime and your code is nuch easier to read!!

Comment: This code was given to me for practice. I think the code increments the value given in by 1. But I am confused because I thought it would actually change the input to its next ascii value.

Answer (score 1):

```
// return an integer given a character pointer, a string.
int f(char *s) {
  // Set current position to start of string
  char *p = s;
  // Initialise carry flag to '1'.
  int c = 1;
  // Move position past leading spaces
  while (*p == ’ ’)
    ++p;
  // Check remaining characters are in the set {'0','1',..,'9'}
  while (*p != ’\0’) {
    // If they are not, return with an error
    if ( *p < ’0’ || *p > ’9’ ) {
      printf("Error!\n"); return 0;
    }
++p; }
  // Now counting back from the end of the string
  for (--p; p >= s; --p) {
    // Turn a space into a '0'; 
    if (*p == ’ ’) *p = ’0’;
    // Increment the digit by the value of the carry; one or zero
    *p += c;
    // This might cause a further carry, capture that
    if (*p > ’9’) {
      *p = ’0’; c = 1;
    } else
      c = 0;
// if no carry, break, else keep on with the carry
    if (c == 0) break;
}
  // If still carrying passed the end of the space, call an error.
  if (c != 0) {
    printf("Error!\n");
    return 0;
}
return 1; }
```

Essentially: If the input is a digit string, add one; might need a leading space and will use it if the input is all '9's.

Comment: The whole `for (--p; p >= s; --p)` loop reduces to `*(--p) += 1; c = 0;` by the way.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. Seem to have managed to read the critical line backwards; now makes some sense.